# Developer Support?

Tags: development

Is there an official channel for developers. I tried to bring up the slack channel they had on the developer documentation but it seems to be offline. I'm stuck with an issue on the app that I'm trying to develop and can't find an answer/solution anywhere. I'm a newbie dev.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for elementary I assume you are using Vala? There is an [IRC](https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.gimp.org#vala) listed over on [planet Vala](https://planet.vala-project.org/). Perhaps someone on there will be able to provide assistance.

Otherwise, I think here on the elementary stackexchange is currently the best place if the issue is very elementary specific.

Good luck with your app!